# What is the best way to code a Java TCP client (C# server)?

Tags: java, tcpclient

I have a server written in C# and need to talk to it from Java 1.6. I need to connect to the server, maintain the connection, and send messages in both directions. The messages are an int (length of the message) and then an XML file.

What is the best way to do this? I know Java well but I've never done TCP from Java (have done it from C#). So I have no idea what the best way to do this is. Speed is not an issue and simplicity is useful.

thanks - dave

Comment: There are tons of Java networking tutorials, books and documentation out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to build a Java client using Socket API.  It's pretty simple to do.

```
try {
   Socket socket = new Socket( host, port );
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ) );
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream() ) );

   out.println("HELO");
   String response = in.readLine();
   System.out.println( response );
} finally {
   in.close();
   out.close();

   socket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only exchanging integers, you might want to use the classes Socket and DataOutputStream (for sending) and DataInputStream (for receiving).
I highly recommend to make the use of threads.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, check out [this tiny demo](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/).

From there, the helpers provided by [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) may clean up some of the lower-level work.